# Create two methods accepting a number as a parameter, one that squares the number and one that cubes the number

Tags: java

I have managed to do part of this question but am having an issue with the cube method.
I need to call the square method from within the cube method to return the cube result.
Example: To square the number 5 the result will be 25. I then call this method in to the cube method to return the answer 125.
Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong please?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ExamPaper2011
{
public static void main(String [] args){

    int totalSquared = 0;
    int totalCubed = 0;

    cubedNumber(totalSquared, totalCubed);
}

 public static int squaredNumber(int totalSquared){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a number to square: ");
    int numSquare = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You entered " + numSquare);
    totalSquared = (int) Math.pow (numSquare, 2); 
    System.out.println("The number squared is " + totalSquared);
    return totalSquared;
}

public static int cubedNumber(int totalSquared, int totalCubed){
    squaredNumber(totalSquared);
    totalSquared = (int) Math.sqrt(totalSquared * totalSquared);
    System.out.println(totalSquared);
    totalCubed = totalSquared;
    totalCubed = (int) Math.pow (numSquare, 3); 
    return totalCubed;
}

}
```

The method cubedNumber seems to return a 0. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Please forgive my basic code. This is a class session.

Here is the answer. Thank you again all.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ExamPaper2011
{
public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a number to square and cube: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    cubedNumber(n);

}

public static int squaredNumber(int n){//Question 4
    System.out.println("You entered " + n);
    n = n * n;
    System.out.println("Squared = " + n);
    return n;
}

public static int cubedNumber(int n){
    squaredNumber(n); 
    n = n * squaredNumber(n);
    System.out.println("Cubed = " + n);
    return n;
}

}
```

I appreciate this great feedback. Really helps. Thank you all.

Comment: Wouldn't cubed just multiply the squared times the original number? Why would you take the square root of something you just squared?

Comment: your math is wrong. you're trying to do `5 ^ 2 ^ 3` (cubing the squared value). you state you want `5 ^ 2` and `5 ^ 3`.

Comment: @Dave Newton - Yes, I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about moving user input checking part out of your logic methods?

```
public class ExamPaper2011
{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        //here you get user input, maybe ask user what calculation he wants to do ^2 Or ^3
        //...get n from user input.
        //if he wants square
        print squaredNumber(n);
        //if he wants cubed
        print cubedNumber(n);
    }

    public static int squaredNumber(int n){
        return n*n;

    }

    public static int cubedNumber(int n){
        return n*squaredNumber(n);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you Kent. 
I dont know why I tried to use Math.sqrt. The thinking behind this was to try to revert the squared number back to its original int (5 in this case) and then use 5 ^ 3.
I was obviously wrong but this is how we learn. Thanks all though.
I understand now. =]

Comment: I would use `n*n*n` for the `cubedNumber` method, for purposes of simplicity, and perhaps speed.

Comment: @syb0rg reuse that `squredmethod()` is a requirement of OP's question. `"I need to call the square method from within the cube method to return the cube result"`

Comment: I know that was a requirement.  I was just stating that to the OP if he uses code like this for a later project of his/hers.

Comment: @Kent What I have noted is how I seem to make things so difficult. Looking at my original code and then looking at the answer, my logic seems all over the place (originally). Many thanks though.